# How to obtain OS directory

Tags: java, windows, directory

I,m looking for some method that can let me obtain (in windows) the directory where windows is saved (for example in my PC it will return "C:\windows".

I need it because I have to call this method

```
public static void openFileWithNotepad(String pathFileTxt) throws InterruptedException, IOException
{
    if(System.getProperty("os.name").toUpperCase().contains("Windows".toUpperCase()))
    {
            String program = "C:/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe";
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(program + " " + pathFileTxt);
    }
...
}
```

I want to use some method to switch "C:/WINDOWS" with the OS installation folder, in order to use this program on different pcs.

P.S.: If someone know, I'd like also to know how to use this method on UNIX OSs :)

Thank you for understanding!

Comment: Why don't you just run `notepad.exe` and let the system work out where to find it from its path?

Comment: And rather than assuming Notepad is the default editor you can do this: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start myfile.txt");` which will open the text file in the user's default editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(pathFileTxt));
```

Works for any file for which there is an associated program, on any OS that supports Java 1.6+.  See [Desktop.open(File)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) for details.

Answer (score 1):

i believe this should work:

```
System.getenv("WINDIR")
```

also, notepad doesn't tend to exist on unix, so i'm not sure where you are going with that...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
System.getenv("windir")
```

for windows.

I'm not sure about other OSs.

Answer (score 0):

`System.getenv("WINDIR")` may work for you.